# How can I make all fonts with all font faces show a sample string for comparison?

Tags: linux, fonts

For a specific task I want to select a decent font. For that I want to compare the text “E G PM” for all my installed fonts (or even more) on a Linux system (Ubuntu in this case). Especially the bold face of a font (if it has any) will more likely match my requirements.

**A quick visual viewing will probably sort 90% out already, so I was thinking of seeing a list of my string in the different font faces available on my system.**

The font viewers/managers I tried are not up for the task. Which app could help me here or how can I quickly solve my problem otherwise?

The apps I tried are:

- fontmatrix

  - version 0.6.0+svn20110930 (0.9.99)
  - a bug hinders your configured text to be shown (font name is always shown)
  - it does not show the bold face of a font in the list (just regular)
- gnome-specimen

  - you have to add each font face individually (2-3 clicks) to seem them
  - you see substituted fonts (if glyph is not in font) without being warned/told
- fontypython crashes at startup on this Ubuntu bionic system
- fontmanager.app is unusable in i3 window manager
- gwaterfall

  - text is fixed to “Lazy dog...”
  - needs each font selected individually (4 clicks at least)
- font-manager

  - has a great browse mode, but in that mode it doesn’t show your own text (only font name)
- gnome-font-viewer can’t set text
- typecatcher

  - custom text, yes
  - shows just regular type face for each font (i.e. not bold or others)
  - requires 1 click to see the font
  - doesn’t show system fonts(?), only a big selection of downloadables
- Opcion

  - horrible user interface
  - doesn’t show bold type face (and others) in the list
- FontViewer

  - makes fonts look ugly (doesn’t antialias or whatnot)
  - no list, no bold face
- kfontview

  - doesn’t find system fonts itself (select font with “Open...” on a font file)
  - doesn’t do lists of fonts

Comment: FontBase seems to have the features you need https://fontba.se/

Comment: @contemplator Not bad. It does not load system fonts, though.

Comment: yeah, you need to manually add them, drag and drop the `/usr/share/fonts` folder into the app window.

Comment: @contemplator took like 10min to add `/usr/share` (~900 font files)

Answer (score 3):

I've installed Fontvuer under 18.04 and it's working pretty good.

It installs as a snap application.

[image: Fontvuer Screenshot]

Comment: At the top I see “400(Normal)”. Does that mean it shows only one font face per font (and not all it contains)? And the other way around: if you set it to “900” it still shows all fonts, even if they have no bold face (by showing the regular face)?

Comment: @RobertSiemer Yes (it will only show one face) and Yes (It will show the regular face if doesn't have any other). The "I" Button is better: You will get the Italic face for those that support it and a yellow warning mark for the others.